# Does groovy implicitly call find on Matcher when cast to boolean?

Tags: groovy

When I do like this

```
println "line with 1 digit" =~ /\d+/
```

It returns

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=\d+ region=0,17 lastmatch=]
```

But when I cast it to boolean - it return `true` or `false` depending on whether it was able to find the pattern in the string

```
println ((boolean) "line with 1 digit" =~ /\d+/) // true
println ((boolean) "line with no digits" =~ /\d+/) // false
```

Does that mean that during cast to `boolean` it invokes `find` method implicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "[groovy truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)" : a set of rules to coerce an instance to a boolean.

Under the hood, Groovy calls the method `asBoolean()` on this object. This method can be implemented on a class, or injected through a category. Look at the various "asBoolean" methods in [DefaultGroovyMethods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) or the implementation of [asBoolean(Matcher)](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.java#L124) :

```
public static boolean asBoolean(Matcher matcher) {
    RegexSupport.setLastMatcher(matcher);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Comment: I think the original question is asking if `find` is called during the process.

Comment: i have added an answer more explicit, but i would like to show there is no magic in the process ;-) when you know how it works, it's easy to find this kind of information

Comment: But in the end it still calls `find` method