# Check how many regex match groups exist, then use them

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm looking to match a regular expression in Groovy, check how many groups were returned, then use one of those groups, but am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

if I call `match.groupCount()` before `match.group(1)`

```
def match = "Some text" =~ /(text)/
if (match.groupCount() >= 1) {
    print match.group()  // error
}

// or

def match = "Some text" =~ /(text)/
if (match) {
    print match.group()  // success
}
```

Comment: My actual code doesn't require this behavior, but the fact that it presents this way shows me that I don't understand Groovy's regex behavior as well as I ought to.

Comment: Are you asking how many matches? As stated below you need to call find() or matches() first. Then groupCount() and group(n) will work. But find() stops at first match, so you need to call it repeatedly to determine the total number of matches.

Comment: There are some extension methods for Matcher that can make this easier.

Comment: You don't need a capturing group if you want the whole matched substring. group(0) will return that.

Comment: @emilles in this case I do need the capturing group (I'm not capturing the whole text)

Answer (score -1):

problem in your first variant that before calling `groupCount()` you have to call `find()`or `matches()`

```
def match = "Some text" =~ /(text)/
if (match.find()) {
    println match.groupCount()
    print match.group()  // error
}
```

the `if (match) {...}` from your second case actually calls `asBoolean()` that calls `find()` on matcher

and there are some simpler variants

```
("Some text 2 text" =~ /text/).each{
    println it
}
```

or

```
println (("Some text 2 text" =~ /text/).collect())
```

Comment: just found there was an answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529357/does-groovy-implicitly-call-find-on-matcher-when-cast-to-boolean

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question as-asked. `match.groupCount()` returns `1` as expected, so I don't appear to need to call `find` or `matches` first. Additionally, per your code, `match.group()` still throws an error after `match.groupCount()`. That's the crux of my question: why?

Comment: just read documentation how [java Matcher works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()).  Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations:  matches, lookingAt, find. So, before any other method call, you have to call one of those.

Comment: Your advice doesn't match the observed result of this code. This is NAA as-written.